# Trying to navigate a form with the enter key - freezes on 'display:none' inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the following jQuery to allow a user to navigate a form with the enter key. It works, however, some of the inputs I created get turned off using `display:none` based on the user’s responses.

When the user approaches one of these off inputs, it freezes. It will not continue to the next input. I can’t hide the input using `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` instead because neither option will work for this specific purpose.

Is there a line of code I can add to the jQuery that says “skip input if display = none”? Or is there an easier method altogether?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allInputs = $(':text:visible');
    $(":text").on("keyup", function() {
        if (event.key !== "Enter") return;
        event.preventDefault(); {
            var nextInput = allInputs.get(allInputs.index(this) + 1);
            if (nextInput) {
                nextInput.focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):valid ~ .remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input" pattern="(1)" placeholder=" ">
<input>
<input>
<input class="remove">

<br>

<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
```

Comment: I tested your code in the snippet and it isn't freezing or anything

Comment: You have to answer the first input with a "1". Then it will freeze on the third input.

Comment: @d50org Just updated my answer with a description explaining what's going on. This can be fixed by ensuring that allInputs contains elements that are actually focusable. Iinputs must be visible to be focusable.

Comment: Also as a suggestion, simply things and don't use complicated CSS for functionality that can be done simply with JavaScript (unless you have to). The other way around is also recommend (don't code too much in JavaScript that's more suitable in CSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because inputs get shown/hidden after page load (document ready) you should re-query the visible inputs.

This is how I changed your code in the `ready` event handler: I moved `allInputs` initialization inside of the `keyup` so it is calculated every time. This is because inputs can be shown and hidden dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":text").on("keyup", function() {
        var allInputs = $('input:visible');
        if (event.key !== "Enter") return;
        event.preventDefault(); {
            var nextInput = allInputs.get(allInputs.index(this) + 1);
            if (nextInput) {
                nextInput.focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is no longer needed, disable it and it will work properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allInputs = $(':text:visible');
    $(":text").on("keyup", function() {
        if (event.key !== "Enter") return;
        event.preventDefault(); {
            var nextInput = allInputs.get(allInputs.index(this) + 1);
            if (nextInput) {
                nextInput.focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):valid ~ .remove {
  display: none; disabled
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input" pattern="(1)" placeholder=" ">
<input>
<input>
<input class="remove">

<br>

<input>
<input>
<input>
<input>
```